# Please help to amend this script that can automatically reboot server by condition

Tags: centos

please could someone help me to correct below scripts that can automatically reboot Centos 5 server once the memory less than 85 and server load over 3. I found this script via Google,I checked it and found there are syntax errors,but I know nothing on bash script programming,so I need your help ,thanks in advance

```
#!/bin/sh
#usage: */2 * * * * root /root/checkload.sh

FREE_MEM_MIN="50"
# 设置最大系统负载
SYS_LOAD_MAX="3"

RESTART_FREE_MEM_MIN="500"

NAME_LIST="httpd mysqld"
for NAME in $NAME_LIST
do

    FREE_MEM=`free -m|grep Mem|awk '{print $4}'`

    #FREE_MEM=`free -m|grep Mem|awk '{print $3}'`

    SYS_LOAD=`uptime | awk '{print $(NF-2)}' | sed 's/,//'`

    MEM_VULE=`awk 'BEGIN{print('"$FREE_MEM"'<'"$FREE_MEM_MIN"'?"1":"0")}'`
    LOAD_VULE=`awk 'BEGIN{print('"$SYS_LOAD"'>='"$SYS_LOAD_MAX"'?"1":"0")}'`


    #LOAD_VULE="1"
    #echo $(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") "DEBUG $NAME" "(FREE_MEM:$FREE_MEM|$MEM_VULE,LOAD:$SYS_LOAD|$LOAD_VULE)">> /var/log/autoreboot_debug.log



    if [ $MEM_VULE = 1 ] || [ $LOAD_VULE = 1 ] ;then

        echo $(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") "killall $NAME" "(FREE_MEM:$FREE_MEM,LOAD:$SYS_LOAD)">> /var/log/autoreboot.log

        service $NAME stop
        sleep 3

        skill $NAME

        sleep 10
 for i in 1 2 3
 do
  FREE_MEM=`free -m|grep Mem|awk '{print $4}'`
  MEM_VULE=`awk 'BEGIN{print('"$FREE_MEM"'>='"$RESTART_FREE_MEM_MIN"'?"1":"0")}'`
  if [ `pgrep $NAME | wc -l` -le 0 ] && [ $MEM_VULE = 1 ]
  then
   service $NAME start
   sleep 15
   echo "AutoStart:" $(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") "start $NAME" `ps -ef | grep $NAME | wc -l` > /var/log/autoreboot.log
  fi
 done


        echo $(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") "start $NAME" "(FREE_MEM:$FREE_MEM,LOAD:$SYS_LOAD)" >> /var/log/autoreboot.log
    else
 MEM_VULE=`awk 'BEGIN{print('"$FREE_MEM"'>='"$RESTART_FREE_MEM_MIN"'?"1":"0")}'`
 if [ `pgrep $NAME | wc -l` -le 0 ] && [ $MEM_VULE = 1 ]
 then
  service $NAME start
  sleep 15
  echo "AutoStart:" $(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") "start $NAME" `ps -ef | grep $NAME | wc -l` > /var/log/autoreboot.log
 else
  echo "$NAME very health!(FREE_MEM:$FREE_MEM,LOAD:$SYS_LOAD)" > /dev/null
 fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why do you post a completely different version after I cleaned the first one up? And more important: Why don't you tell us what kind of error reports you get when running this script?

Comment: Rebooting a server when there is a problem isn't really a solution. It would be better to know what is causing the problem and acting accordingly.

Comment: because the first version is for debian not CentOS,it was my overlook,so I amend it."

Comment: In general you don't reboot a server when things are acting nuts. You figure out what's wrong, and fix that problem. It's kind of the difference between fixing the hole in a tire and pumping air into it every two days...they both "work" but one is obviously better as a solution rather than a workaround.

Comment: @user167043 <Lecture> The core principle of system administration (or any engineering practice) is to fix the **real problem**, not flail around wildly (in your case restarting services) because you don't know what's causing the problem.  Do yourself and your employer a favor: Find and fix the REAL issue, or at least thoroughly understand WHY you're restarting services (and tell us when you ask for help).  Simply bouncing systems/services because you hit an arbitrary memory or load threshold is not generally considered to be an acceptable way of managing systems. </Lecture>

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), it seems to be capable of what you need and more.

Comment: I would like to use script,as I think monit is complicated to setup

Comment: Monit takes about five minutes to set up.

Comment: @ceejayoz why did you vote down ? what was wrong with this question do you think ?

Comment: Who says I'm the one who voted it down? Votes are anonymous.

Comment: Also, too lazy to follow up on suggestions --

Comment: @user167043, use it if it fits, or don't. However, as others pointed out, you *seem* to think that putting the script that will *restart* the server is a good thing. Here are some further comments: 1) restarting the server is bad, slightly less bad is restarting services 2) monit is a tool for general monitoring - you might actually get better insight into what is going on with it and you might be able to use it to monitor other things, too 3) a script that you have hunted down on the internets and modified using SE site is not unlike using duct tape to fix a car engine, it's simply wrong

Answer (score 1):

This script doesn't automatically reboot Centos 5 server on high memory usage or high cpu.. It restart the services you specify in. Here is the corrected version for GNU Bash-4.1:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set your parameters here:

FREE_MEM_MIN="50"
SYS_LOAD_MAX="3"
RESTART_FREE_MEM_MIN="500"

NAME_LIST="httpd mysqld"

# Dont touch below this

for NAME in $NAME_LIST
do
    FREE_MEM=`free -m|grep Mem|awk '{print $4}'`
    SYS_LOAD=`uptime | awk '{print $(NF-2)}' | sed 's/,//'`
    MEM_VULE=`awk 'BEGIN{print('"$FREE_MEM"'<'"$FREE_MEM_MIN"'?"1":"0")}'`
    LOAD_VULE=`awk 'BEGIN{print('"$SYS_LOAD"'>='"$SYS_LOAD_MAX"'?"1":"0")}'`
    #echo $(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") "DEBUG $NAME" "(FREE_MEM:$FREE_MEM|$MEM_VULE,LOAD:$SYS_LOAD|$LOAD_VULE)">> /var/log/autoreboot_debug.log
    if [ $MEM_VULE = 1 ] || [ $LOAD_VULE = 1 ] ;then
         echo $(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") "killall $NAME" "(FREE_MEM:$FREE_MEM,LOAD:$SYS_LOAD)">> /var/log/autoreboot.log
         service $NAME stop
         sleep 3
         skill $NAME
         sleep 10
         for i in 1 2 3
         do
             FREE_MEM=`free -m|grep Mem|awk '{print $4}'`
             MEM_VULE=`awk 'BEGIN{print('"$FREE_MEM"'>='"$RESTART_FREE_MEM_MIN"'?"1":"0")}'`
             if [ `pgrep $NAME | wc -l` -le 0 ] && [ $MEM_VULE = 1 ]
             then
             service $NAME start
                 sleep 15
                 echo "AutoStart:" $(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") "start $NAME" `ps -ef | grep $NAME | wc -l` > /var/log/autoreboot.log
             fi
         done
         echo $(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") "start $NAME" "(FREE_MEM:$FREE_MEM,LOAD:$SYS_LOAD)" >> /var/log/autoreboot.log
    else
         MEM_VULE=`awk 'BEGIN{print('"$FREE_MEM"'>='"$RESTART_FREE_MEM_MIN"'?"1":"0")}'`
         if [ `pgrep $NAME | wc -l` -le 0 ] && [ $MEM_VULE = 1 ]
         then
             service $NAME start
             sleep 15
             echo "AutoStart:" $(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") "start $NAME" `ps -ef | grep $NAME | wc -l` > /var/log/autoreboot.log
         else
             echo "$NAME very health!(FREE_MEM:$FREE_MEM,LOAD:$SYS_LOAD)" > /dev/null
         fi
    fi
done
```